# Do quark self-energy insertions on external quark lines vanish in the MS scheme?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, renormalization, feynman-diagrams, self-energy

As far as I know, if one wishes to consider quark self energy diagrams inserted on external legs of a scattering amplitude, they cancel with the crossterm diagrams in the on-shell scheme. For this reason, it is not necessary to calculate these specific terms.
Can the same thing be said if one chooses to work in the MS-Scheme? How does it affect the dressed propagator (since the residue of the dressed propagator is simply 1 in on-shell scheme, but not in MS)?